# Create a delete page form in Yii Framework?

Tags: php, html, forms, yii

I know that usually you would just use the integrated CRUD delete button that is in admin however for my purposes I am requiring an actual page for delete that just has the id in a field and a submit button but so far it just produces the error view so any assistance is appreciated. I have tried to create it the same as my create and update pages are set up, please see the code below:

**The link to the delete page:**

```
<?php echo CHtml::link('Delete Article', array('delete', 'id'=>$pageid)); ?>
```

**The link it produces:**

```
http://local/..../Yii/news/index.php/delete?id=3
```

**The controller:**

```
public function actionDelete($id)
{
$model=$this->loadModel($id);


    if(isset($_POST['news_model']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['news_model'];
        if($model->save())
            $this->redirect('index');
    }

    $this->render(array('delete', array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

**Delete.php:**

```
<h2>Delete a news item</h2>

<?php echo $this->renderPartial('_form2', array('model'=>$model)); ?>
```

**_form2.php**

```
<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
'id'=>'news-model-form',
'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
)); ?>

<div class="form">

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'id'); ?><br>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'id',array('size'=>50,'maxlength'=>128)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'id'); ?>
</div><br>

<div class="row buttons">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Delete a news item'); ?>
</div>

    <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

    </div><!-- form -->
```

Thanks in advance for any help given.

Comment: Its not actuall displaying the code or a error message that is one of the issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got an error in your php synax in **_form2.php**

```
<?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Delete a news item'); ?>
```

more like

```
<?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Delete a news item':'Delete an old item'); ?>
```

See the **Ternary Operator** in [**PHP: Comparison Operators**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

... yet I don't se the point in that sentence, to me it would seem  a little bit more like:

```
<?php if (!$model->isNewRecord) echo CHtml::submitButton("Delete Record"); ?>
```

... but the record is guaranteed to not be new when it is loaded by `$model=$this->loadModel($id);`

Also, In **Delete.php**

```
<?php echo $this->renderPartial('_form2', array('model'=>$model)); ?>
```

would be more like

```
<?php echo $this->renderPartial('_form2', array('model'=>$model), true); ?>
```

or

```
<?php $this->renderPartial('_form2', array('model'=>$model)); ?>
```

Seel the documentation [`renderPartial()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#renderPartial-detail), specially pay attention to its return value its third argument. Turns out that you're actually echoing NULL. which explains why there is no display.

Comment: Ok thanks, Ill test it later, is this the reason why the page isn't loading? Or is it down to the fact that it doesn't see delete.php as a page. Thanks.

Comment: I just realised what you are saying, i wasnt saying NEW item I was saying news as in latest news. :) but I will try.